# slower start for 18v dc motor

Tags: motor, dc

I have a dc motor that comes from a 18V corless drill. I made a small waterpump that will pump maybe 10minutes at a time 5times a day maybe 20 days a year.
I use the motor to drive the pump. The problem is it has a very thin shaft and becuase it starts at full speed immidiately when it starts, it breaks may attachement to the waterpump. It draws 1.12 amps at full speed,I use a 12v battery to drive it. Is there a simple electronic circuit I can build to cause it to get to full speed in maybe .5 seconds or 1second instead of immidiate full speed? So that there is not so much force on my attachment mechanism?
It does not have to be variable, just soften the initial start every time.

Comment: Sure thing! Is it a brushed DC motor as in only two wires going in to the motor? If yes, you are looking a for a PWM soft start. A NTC resistor comes to mind too.

Comment: Perhaps a TDK B57127P0100M301? You might need higher 25 degree resistance and depending on your run current, more or less current rating.

Comment: Hi wnny, yes it only has two wires.How would I connect the NTC resistor?

Comment: In series with either plus or minus. If you don’t want to buy several NTC and try out the behavior, the full load run current would be needed. Is 1.12 A with the water pump and water in it? If yes, I would aim for an NTC with about 1.5 A rating and preferably under 1 ohm of resistance @ hot.

Comment: Use the control circuit that was in the drill, will match the motor.

Comment: @winny The 1.12 A is no load current

Comment: On top of what @SolarMike said, if the original drill has a torque limiter, use that and set it to a low value and it will act as a mechanical soft start of sorts.

Comment: Right. Can you test or estimate the full load current with the water pump?

Comment: @Solar Mike I would have but I accidentily connected it in reversed polarity and it burned, really angry with myself

Comment: @winny  Unfortunately I cant get full load Amps, when I start it with the pump it run for a second and then strips my coupler to the pump.The shaft is only 3mm dia. and I made my pump shaft a pipe with 3mm inside dia. The motor shaft has a flat side where I improvised a insert to lock it to the pump's hollow shaft. But my insert breaks when It starts. For practicaql reasons torque converter will not fit. I am now trying to drill a hole through the pump and motor shafts and put a pin through, but a soft start would probably be better.

Comment: I am not sure how to reply to you both at the same time, but thank you for your answers

Comment: If you have never successfully driven the pump long enough to determine how much current the motor draws at full speed, you must consider that the motor does not have the capacity to drive the pump for even 10 minutes at a time. The fact that the pump shaft is much larger than the moto shaft is a strong indication that the motor torque capacity is not high enough.

Comment: I let the motor run now and braked it by clamping the shaft, the highest amps I got was 4Amp. But I am pretty sure my little pump will never put so much strain on the motor, more likely 2 to 2.5 amps

Comment: I made the pump myself from pvc pipe components, so I decided on the shaft size, i chose that size because it fits perfectly over the motor shaft, its not really much larger. So in this case the shaft size does not mean much as far as power is concerned

Comment: my impeller diameter is only 40mm. so I think it wont strain the motor too much, but It's all really guessing

Comment: Right. Do you still have the planetary gearbox and torque limiter from the drill? Use that. If NTC, choose a current rating slightly higher than your maximum estimated full load run current.

Comment: Perhaps more suitable if your run current is in the 4 A range: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cantherm/MF72-005D11/317-1177-ND/1190952

Comment: Thank you I will try the NTC, much appreciated

Comment: Will the NTC resistor limit the current for a very short period - is that how it works?

Comment: If I knew the load current, is there a calculation I can do to determine the Ohms and Amps of the NTC i should use?

Comment: It works by having high resistance at room temperature, limiting the initial current. As current passes, it heats up gradually over about one second (varies, check the datasheet) and decreases the resistance until it reaches an equilibrium. Choose the cold ohm to be sufficiently high to drop say half of your supply voltage according to U=IR. Choose the hot resistance to be low enough to not drop more than a few % of your supply voltage according to U=IR. Choose a current rating slightly higher than your worst case continuous run current.

Comment: Really helpfull thank you

Comment: Let me know if it works and I’ll write a proper answer so we can close this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109666/discussion-on-question-by-redge-slower-start-for-18v-dc-motor).